# Index signature is missing in type '{}'.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface defined like this:

```
export interface RelationsObj = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key: string]: Relation[];
  };
}
```

As far as I understand, this could account for an object like this:

```
{
  a: {
    b: [relation1, relation2],
    c: [relation3, relation4]
  }
}
```

with any number of first-level properties ('a'). Therefore, it could just as well be an empty object, simply with 0 properties.

In a function I call, an outcome has the above type, and a possible outcome is `{}`. Now Typescript makes an issue of this, which I don't understand. The output type is defined like so:

```
// FYI 
interface CalculatePositionsResult {
  relations: RelationsObj;
}
```

And the error I get is this:

```
Type '(data: any) => { relations: {}; }' is not assignable to type '(props: any) => CalculatePositionsResult'.
  Call signature return types '{ relations: {}; }' and 'CalculatePositionsResult' are incompatible.
    The types of 'relations' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'RelationsObj'.
        Index signature is missing in type '{}'.ts(2322)
```

It is solved when I allow for empty objects explicitly:

```
export type RelationsObj = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key: string]: Relation[];
  };
} | {}
```

But I don't understand why this is necessary.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Could you please include a full example with the function that's causing the error? I can't be certain without knowing how the function is defined, but this seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue: https://tsplay.dev/aNnM6w